# Google Cloud API Gateway with Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-api-gateway

I am looking for a working example/tutorial on how I can use Google Cloud API Gateway with microservices/API hosted in GKE.  For example when I try to create an API Gateway and I point it to an existing API on GKE I get the following error:

Backend URL "http://35.xxx.xxx.xxx/legalentities" is forbidden: cannot route requests by IP Address.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what you have tried so far? What is your API configuration, and what steps did you take to deploy your API?

Answer (score 2):

GKE by default produces ip address for ingress controller or load balancer and API Gateway does not allow ip address to be hostname for x-google-backend. This is a problem, hopefully it will be resolved the API Gateway comes out for beta.

I faced the same situation. This is how I got around to it (using nip.io):

```
/products/getoptions:
    get:
      summary: get product options
      operationId: getProductOptions
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://35.xxx.xxx.xxx.nip.io/api/productservice
        path_translation: APPEND_PATH_TO_ADDRESS
      parameters:
        - name: x-access-token
          in: header
          description: Access Token
          required: true
          type: string
        - name: x-refresh-token
          in: header
          description: Refresh Token
          required: true
          type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          schema:
            type: object
```

Comment: Have you tried to assign a domain name (DNS wise) to the `IP` of your `Ingress`/`Loadbalancer` IP?

Comment: Hi Dawid Kurk, yes, however you are suggesting that I set the address with an external IP/DNS... this defeats the purpose of using API Gateway..

Comment: I added two possible options, putting a load balancer in front of your application may be an option. Another option is to put your internet-facing application in a managed cloud run, which produces an fqdn.

Comment: @Ali Nahid Could you please share me way to manage it without nio.io. i'm not much familiar with nip.io, is it just a string?

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing, API Gateway is still in [Beta](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs), so it may not be fully functional and documentation may be scarce. One of the shortcomings of API Gateway, for now, is that your GKE environment produces an internet-facing service which is accessible by IP address only. However, you will need to put an FQDN inside your `openapi.yaml` (see below). That is where your error probably comes from.

Two options to mitigate this problem:

- Use a load-balancer in front of the GKE IP address. So that you can use the FQDN of the load balancer. However, I am not sure if authentication will still work in this setup, and users may be able to bypass the API gateway.
- Deploy your internet-facing application in a managed Cloud Run. This will always produce an FQDN. Which you can just fill in the `x-google-backend address`. You will need to configure serverless VPC access for Cloud Run to let the application communicate with your GKE cluster.

  ```
  swagger: '2.0'
  info:
    title: API_ID optional-string
    description: Sample API on API Gateway with a Google Cloud Functions backend
    version: 1.0.0
  schemes:
    - https
  produces:
    - application/json
  paths:
    /hello:
      get:
        summary: Greet a user
        operationId: hello
        x-google-backend:
          address: [FQDN HERE]
        responses:
          '200':
            description: A successful response
            schema:
              type: string
  ```

Comment: I don't think this ans holds any relevance to the asked question. GCP API Gateway allows x-google-backend with fqdn name. However, upon GKE deployed with native load balancer or ingress controller it gives an external IP address, not fqdn. If I try to use this IP address based GKE ingress controller endpoint in the x-google-backend the API gateway throws this error.
I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Nahid, I will update my answer. If there is no requirement to have GKE, a managed cloud run always produces a fqdn, so that could work for now. One could also deploy the internet-facing application in a managed cloud run with serverless vpc access.